# Yii2 Horizontal form

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-basic-app

What I want to do is to change from bootstrap vertical to horizontal form and this is what I've tried:

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
    'layout' => 'horizontal',
    'action' => ['index'],
    'method' => 'get',
    'fieldConfig' => [
        'horizontalCssClasses' => [
            'label' => 'col-sm-2',
            'offset' => 'col-sm-offset-2',
            'wrapper' => 'col-sm-4',
        ],
    ],
]); ?>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <?= $form->field($model, 'firstname') ?>
            <?= $form->field($model, 'lastname') ?>
       </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <?= $form->field($model, 'email') ?>
            <?= $form->field($model, 'bla') ?>
       </div>
    </div>
<?php ActiveForm::end() ?>
```

but it gave me an error Setting unknown property: yii\widgets\ActiveForm::layout
Please help!!!

Comment: Try :   'options' => ['class' => 'form-horizontal'],

Answer (score 8):

For `layout` option to work `ActiveForm` must be instance of `yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm` instead of `yii\widgets\ActiveForm`.

Change your `use` statement.

Answer (score 4):

In boostrap  you can use

```
<form class="form-inline">  // for inline fields form
```

or

```
<form class="form-horizontal">  // for horizonatal  fields form
```

eg:

```
  <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
      'layout' => 'horizontal',
      'action' => ['index'],
      'method' => 'get',
      'class' => 'form-horizontal',    
  ]); ?>
```